# How can I change the hotkey to Firefox's Search Engine field (next to the address bar)

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

In the Ubuntu version of Firefox, the keybinding to the the Search Engine text-box 
(next to the addressbar) is different to what I am used to (in the Windows version).

Can I change this key form  <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>K</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>E</kbd>?

I've tried `Editable Menu Accelerators`, but that didn't work.

Comment: It's not an answer, so I put it as a comment, but `Ctrl+K` works on Windows too. So you could try that one on both platform.

Comment: A good "just go with it" solution, and I'm usually happy enough to use new shortcut-keys, but my touch-typing becomes a bit ham-fisted with that Ctrl+K and Ctrl+L... I definitely feel happier with  Alt-D and Ctrl+E  (strange, but true)

Comment: Just press Alt+D (with your thumb and index finger) and Tab(with your pinky).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Firefox isn't a GTK application, it won't work with the *Editable Menu Accelerators* option. Also, the [Firefox help page on keyboard shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts#Configuring_keyboard_shortcuts) says, "Firefox does not provide any method of customizing keyboard shortcuts." (It also shows you can use either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Linux versions, but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.)

However, there is a way to do it! There is an extension for Firefox (and other XULRunner applications) called Keyconfig ([install](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi)). According to the [MozillaZine post on the subject](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994):

> keyconfig adds the ability to create new or modify existing shortcuts defined by a  element, but only changing those which itself call a function (those with a command or oncommand attribute) has an effect (all others fulfill only cosmetic purposes it seems and are grayed out).
>
> The configuration screen can be accessed via Tools > Keyconfig (in most Applications) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on MacOS) from the main window.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Don't think that changing a  will always remove the original shortcuts. For Example: You can change the shortcut for Copy in the Bookmarks Manager but the original shortcut will still work (in addition to the new shortcut).

Comment: I'm somewhat late in commenting on this, but I wanted to try it out in a VM first.  I had quite a few teething probelms setting up the VM (I'm an Ubuntu newbie).. Finally got it sorted out.. Your suggested Firefox Add-on works as advertised. Great! Thanks... The only thing I am concerned about is that this Add-on is not listed in Firefox's own Add-on "repository"...  I'm a bit wary of that.  Not that Firefox's own list of Add-ons are necessarily safe, but at least I can read their public feedback...  I just wonder why it isn't in Firefox's repository?...

Comment: PS. re my previous comment: Actually there is heaps of public feedback on the "MozillaZine post on the subject" link you posted... 116 pages to be precise...  but I still wonder why such a great add-on is not listed in Firefox's repository.. I'd love to hear some comments on this.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu, then! That's a great question. Seems to me that MozillaZine is kind of a community of its own, drawing people who like to dig into the inner workings of Firefox. It *does* seem like there is plenty of stuff on MozillaZine that doesn't get posted to [addons.mozilla.org](http://addons.mozilla.org) or the main, official Firefox pages. I'd guess that people there generally feel that stuff is already "out there" and doesn't need the additional effort to put it in a more official place. Your careful attitude about where you get your software is commendable!

Comment: In most recent FF 38, Ctrl+K would open a Firefox default page (no URL, big FF logo with search box). I confirm that it can be changed with the [Keyconfig addon](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi) linked in the answer, and that Ctrl+K does not do anything after changing this.

Comment: The [Keyconfig](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi) addon from the answer works. There is also an addon [Key config](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/key-config/) in the official Firefox repo, but this is *not* the same, and it does *not* work to solve this problem (at least not in FF 38).